# Can I set a default domain for a Windows Authenticated website in IIS7?

Tags: iis-7, domain, authentication, windows-authentication

I have an intranet site using [Windows Authentication](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication). When users are prompted for credentials, they enter:

```
User: domain\username
Pass: SomePassword
```

It'd be nice if they could leave off the `domain\` part which would be filled in with a default domain. I'm willing to give up the ability to login with a server/machine account (non-domain) because we don't use that anyway.

This seems to be possible with BasicAuth but I can't seem to find a reference for how to do it with WindowsAuth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Windows Authentication" means the browser send the credentials of the currently logged on user to the web server; then, if this authentication fails because the user doesn't have enough rights to access the site, he gets prompted for a logon.

The credentials sent automatically by Windows Authentication are ***always*** those of the currently logged on user, including the domain he belongs to; so you can't specify anything here, as it just wouldn't make any sense to do so.

Comment: So if the user is being prompted for credentials this suggests the site is falling back to Forms Auth?

Comment: When I open up IIS Manager and bring up `Authentication` for my site, it shows `Windows Authentication (HTTP 401 Challenge)` as the only enabled option. When I hit the site in Chrome I get a login box--that's what I want to set this for

Comment: Have you tried using just the username (not domain\username?). In my environment at least, logging on with just the username works from Firefox/Chrome/Safari (but not IE oddly enough).

Comment: @MattB: that doesn't work for me--I always must use the domain

Comment: @Michael Haren: Weird - is the user you are trying to login as in the same domain as the server?

Comment: Matt, is by chance the server you tested this against a domain controller? When logging on to a DC, the domain is always implicitly assumed, as it doesn't have any local user database.

Comment: Nope, definitely not a domain controller. Forgot to mention though, I think this is new behavior in IIS7/Windows 2008 - I can duplicate across numerous IIS7 servers, but none of my IIS6 ones.

Comment: At the moment, this is all on one Windows 7 machine. The machine is part of the domain as is my login. Perhaps I will get the behavior you describe once I publish to another server... I apologize if this info changes things--I didn't intentionally withhold it!

Comment: @Michael Haren: lets not discount the possibility that it could be a fluke in my environment - I haven't been able to find documentation on the internet about this new behavior. :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot, there is no way for IIS to set the default domain when using integrated authentication. A popular trick to appease users is to have them login with `username@domain.com` (their UPN in Active Directory terms) instead - this typically matches their e-mail address, and is much more palatable to end users.

Comment: I thought it was a bad idea to use the same domain as used out on the WAN?